# Windows boot manager shows alwasys at startup

Tags: windows-vista

I erased my hard drive and installed a fresh copy of windows Vista Home Premium 32 bit in an Inspiron 530 with an Intel 266 Mhz processor. I installed the OS, and after the installation the Windows Boot Manager always shows at startup. I tried to repair the problem using the OS dvd, but it was impossible. This is frustrating. Please, help!!

Answer (score 0):

GO to run and type following command:

**msconfig**

It will show the System Configuration Windows:

select the tab named **Boot**. In that you will find 2 OS listed in boot manager. one is your current OS and the other one is the your last installed Os's entry. select your last installed OS entry and delete it.

Press Ok button and restart the system. your problem is solved  !!!

Answer (score 0):

I only had one entry, and it would still show.  msconfig was not enough, nor just setting the timeout to 0.

If you do this:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} displaybootmenu no
```

This will remove the boot manager menu from startup